# webservices for Autocomplete extender is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have use ajax auto extender the code is like as

```
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_AutoComplete" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    ServiceMethod="GetNames" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" TargetControlID="txt_AutoComplete"> </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and web services In Autocomplete.asmx is that the web service is not calling

```
[WebMethod]

        public string[] GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            ArrayList sampleList = new ArrayList();

            sampleList.Add("ABC"); sampleList.Add("Hello");

            sampleList.Add("Hi");

            sampleList.Add("Hey");

            ArrayList filteredList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string s in sampleList)
            {

                if (s.ToLower().StartsWith(prefixText.ToLower()))

                    filteredList.Add(s);

            }
            return (string[])filteredList.ToArray(typeof(string));

        }
```

but ajax auto extender is not working

Comment: Does it give an error? anything? please show the full code of your asmx.cs

Comment: The method is not working
Its not calling web method

Comment: It's not calling the web method at all?

Comment: yes the method is not calling at all

Answer (score 0):

U have to use the following above ur required method

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]